# How can i download ICEfaces-1.7.0 Netbeans plugin?

Tags: icefaces, icefaces-3, icefaces-1.8, icefaces-2

kindly help me out in find the **ICEfaces-1.7.0** Netbeans plugins. In the offical site i can see it in the download list but there is not any download link.

You can see it in the following link
http://www.icesoft.org/java/downloads/detail-1-8.jsf

IDE Tool Integration release 3.1.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look it out on following link
http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/21402.page#75203